# Expression that means "as soon as something is finished"

Tags: meaning, phrase-requests, expression-choice

I am looking for an expression that means "right after finishing something, start something". For some reason, the words "fresh off the heels" keep springing up but I googled them and it's not an expression.

Answer (score 6):

Or the idiom:

> on the heels of

The oral examination came on the heels of the qualifying exam.

Comment: Sometimes something happening right after something else is said to be ["hard on the heels of."](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/hard+on+the+heels+of)

Answer (score 0):

> Fresh/hot off the press

This might be what you're thinking of/looking for.

Answer (score -1):

How about "Immediately thereafter"?